# dictionary comprehension of multiple items in set in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I use dictionary comprehension to obtain the average of the student scores

```
co_dct = {"Juan":[90,85,98], "Lana":[94,80,100], "Alicia":[100,90], "Sam":[]}
co_dct = d/d[] for d in co_dct
print(co_dct)
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question, though. Is a `SyntaxError` raised? Add it to your question.

Comment: Is that your question? If so, why not try it and find out? If your question is why isn't that valid syntax: why did you think it would be valid? You aren't actually using a dictionary comprehension.

Comment: Why did you just take it out again? Do you actually *have* a question? Learn [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> co_dct = {"Juan":[90,85,98], "Lana":[94,80,100], "Alicia":[100,90], "Sam":[]}

>>> {k: sum(co_dct[k])/float(len(co_dct[k])) for k in co_dct if co_dct[k]}
{'Juan': 91.0, 'Lana': 91.33333333333333, 'Alicia': 95.0}
```

Note the use of a filter to guard against division by zero errors when the sample list is empty. This results in the loss of keys that have empty samples, but that seems reasonable since you can't produce an average without data.

Since you are using Python 3 another way is to use `statistics.mean()`:

```
>>> from statistics import mean
>>> {k: mean(co_dct[k]) for k in co_dct if co_dct[k]}
{'Lana': 91.33333333333333, 'Alicia': 95, 'Juan': 91}
```

---

A minor optimisation might be to use `co_dct.items()` to avoid multiple dict lookups:

```
>>> {k: mean(values) for k, values in co_dct.items() if values}
```